# Google Drive search files. When use 'me' alias?

Tags: google-drive-api

For my application I need find all user's documents. I using Google Drive Files.list API with query like "'abc@example.com' in owners".  For some users I get empty search results, but these users has a lot of docs. I found that for these users I can fetch all doc with Alias 'me' - "'me' in owners".    My application using 2 legged oauth.
Why I getting different results for 'me' and 'user email' search queries?
Is this a bug?
I didn't find any notes about alias 'me' in official docs, so I am not sure if it is safe to use it or not.

Comment: If the authenticated user's email is the email you're querying with, it's a bug.

Comment: Yes, I using authenticated user's email for query.

Comment: Probably a bug, we'll investigate and provide a solution.